# Is there a way to animate (rotating) my application item within a layer-list definition?

Tags: android, android-drawable

Currently I have the following drawable (`splash.xml`) definition:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:drawable="@color/grey_300"/>

    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

I'm using that for a splash screen by defining an activity as follows:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".SplashActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

That style comes from `styles.xml`:

```
<style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash</item>
</style>
```

, I was wondering if I could some how animate the logo centered on screen (maybe rotating it). What would be the best way to reach it? I already tried to play a bit with `animated-rotate` inside `item` element but no success until now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this will help:

I noticed you used [this](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/splash-screens-the-right-way/) guide. However, someone asked him in comments if he can add animation to his splash screen, his answer was:

> It's not possible to do an animation with the splash screen pattern that I've listed above. The animation would only be available when the app has already loaded.
>
> Outside of this, you can animate a layer list. Just apply it as the background on some view and animate that view.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue and used a workaround. I created a SplashActivity without a layout and a ProgressActivity with a layout for the ProgressBar and used Intents to go from the SplashActivity to the ProgressActivity and from the ProgressActivity to the MainActivity. Some code below. With thanks to the following YouTube video for setting up the ProgressBar in xml: https://www.youtube.com/watch?annotation_id=annotation_1961654299&feature=iv&src_vid=yJ3cP6r8cxU&v=Ok30rN5SUe8

Drawable for the SplashTheme:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <color android:color="#EEEEEE"/>
    </item>

    <item android:id="@android:id/background">


    <shape
            android:shape="ring"
            android:innerRadiusRatio="24"
            android:thickness="18dp"
            android:useLevel="false">
            <solid android:color="#EF9A9A"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="0"
            android:toDegrees="360">
            <shape
                android:shape="ring"
                android:innerRadiusRatio="24"
                android:thickness="18dp"
                android:useLevel="false">
                <gradient
                    android:color="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:angle="0"
                    android:startColor="#D50000"
                    android:type="sweep"
                    android:useLevel="false"/>
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Drawable for the ProgressBar: same as above but with innerRadiusRatio and thickness removed from both shapes.

content-progress xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="nl.braaks55.minesweeper.activities.Progress"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_progress">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center">

        <ProgressBar
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="160dp"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/progress_bar"
            android:max="100"
            android:progress="20"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="@string/loading"
            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

SplashActivity:

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ProgressActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
    }
}
```

ProgressActivity:

```
public class ProgressActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final long DELAY = 3000L;

    TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(ProgressActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    };

    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(timerTask, DELAY);
    }
}
```